# Get Count from two individual tables with different status count

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables in that I'm using two columns column1, column2
where column2 is contained different status id like 1, 2, 3, 4
now I need a query where users in column1 are compared with all the status present in column2 and get the count individually
and compare one particular status wheather it is greater than or equals to 10 and count for remaining status should be 0 for each particular user [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WQMt.png)

Comment: please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: Actually I'm trying to add the table but it is not working in this comment

Comment: It would be great if you add this in your question

Comment: I've given you the example output

Comment: Please refrain from using images/screenshots as a medium for code/data. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No images please. Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Please go through this link once: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Once you have edited the question satisfactorily, please tag us back here, so that we can attempt an answer.